# How to get or patch particular field in given yaml using yq when there are multiple manifests present in same file?

Tags: yaml, yq

I have a yaml config file which looks like this;

```
apiVersion: controller.kubeslice.io/v1alpha1
kind: Cluster
metadata:
  name: kind-worker1  # kind-worker-1 
  namespace: kubeslice-avesha # kubeslice-avesha
spec:
  networkInterface: eth0
---
apiVersion: controller.kubeslice.io/v1alpha1
kind: Cluster
metadata:
  name: kind-worker2 # kind-worker-2
  namespace: kubeslice-avesha # kubeslice-avesha
spec:
  networkInterface: eth0
```

Now how to get or patch the *name* field of specific the cluster object ? When I execute;

```
yq '.metadata.name' config.yaml
```

then I get the respective values from both manifests;

```
kind-worker1
---
kind-worker2
```

Or, if I try to patch using;

```
yq '.metadata.name = "kind-worker"' config.yaml
```

both the fields get updated;

```
apiVersion: controller.kubeslice.io/v1alpha1
kind: Cluster
metadata:
  name: kind-worker # kind-worker-1 
  namespace: kubeslice-avesha # kubeslice-avesha
spec:
  networkInterface: eth0
---
apiVersion: controller.kubeslice.io/v1alpha1
kind: Cluster
metadata:
  name: kind-worker # kind-worker-2
  namespace: kubeslice-avesha # kubeslice-avesha
spec:
  networkInterface: eth0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `select` to filter the contents before querying/updating.

For example, to query the first one, use `document_index == 0` as filter (counting starts at `0`):

```bash
yq 'select(document_index == 0).metadata.name' config.yaml
```

```
kind-worker1
```

Or update the one where `.metadata.name` equals `"kind-worker2"` (which is the second one):

```bash
yq 'select(.metadata.name == "kind-worker2").metadata.name = "xy"' config.yaml
```

```yaml
apiVersion: controller.kubeslice.io/v1alpha1
kind: Cluster
metadata:
  name: kind-worker1 # kind-worker-1 
  namespace: kubeslice-avesha # kubeslice-avesha
spec:
  networkInterface: eth0
---
apiVersion: controller.kubeslice.io/v1alpha1
kind: Cluster
metadata:
  name: xy # kind-worker-2
  namespace: kubeslice-avesha # kubeslice-avesha
spec:
  networkInterface: eth0
```

Note: You can query and update all fields independently.

Comment: Thanks. But it requires to have known values already assigned to those fields I want to edit. How to handle the case when both *name*s are empty ?
Also what to do if I want to get the first cluster *name*?

Comment: @MridulGain I added another filter example using `document_index`.